# JSX conditional rendering syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have the following component:

```
export const Checkmark = props => (
  <Layout {...props}>
    { 
      if(props.checked){
        <Icon name="checkmarkBlue" small />
      } 
    }
  </Layout>
)
```

my linting is complaining about the "if" saying (unexpected token)

[image]

Comment: There's [an entire page about this in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the brackets there must be *expressions*. You could change it to a ternary:

```
  { props.checked ? <Icon name="checkmarkBlue" small /> : "" }
```

Alternatively if you really need statements, you might use an IIFE

```
{(function(){
  if(props.checked)
    return <Icon name="checkmarkBlue" small />;
  //...
  return "";
})()}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`React#github`](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction

you should use `short-circuit` instead.

```
<Layout {...props}>
    {     
      props.checked && <Icon name="checkmarkBlue" small />     
    }
```

Or

```
   render(){

      let myHtml = "";

      if(props.checked){
        myHtml = <Icon name="checkmarkBlue" small /> 
      }

      return (<Layout {...props}> { myHtml}</Layout>);
    }
```

Comment: You might want to link to a current version of the docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Comment: @JordanRunning thanks man.